# Adding custom validation jQuery Plugin Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery plugin  validation , i want to ignore   the default values in a text box. i am addng cusotm validation in jQuery as follow. but it always return false.  can any one help me what may be the issues in my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod("defaultInvalid", function (value, element) {
        switch (element.value) {
            case "First Name":
                if (element.name == "First Name") return false;
        }
    });
    $("#frmReserv").validate({
        rules: {
            FName: "required defaultInvalid",
        },
        messages: {
            FName: "Please Enter Your Name",
        },
    });
});
```

And Html field is

```
<input type="text" value="First Name" name="FName"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer works in older versions of IE.

---

This is the custom method I've used in the past…

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("defaultInvalid", function(value, element) {
    return value != element.defaultValue;
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/45J2Q/**

---

To automatically hide/show the default text on focus/blur, add a class to the input and use this…

```
$('.autoclear')
.on('focus', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == $(this).prop('defaultValue')) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
})
.on('blur', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).val($(this).prop('defaultValue'));
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" value="First Name" name="FName" class="autoclear" />
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/45J2Q/1/**

Answer (score 0):

Use [HTML5 placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) attribute

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="FName"/>
```

than you don't need to make a check for default value.

```
$("#frmReserv").validate({
        rules: {
                FName: "required",
        },
```

Poyfill for placeholder https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Comment: Now also it returns false, even i type any thing in textbox.. it shows "Please enter your Name"

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" value="" name="FName"/>
```

Value="" will check at the time of jquery validation